# Using actionListener

Tags: java, awt

I'm a student and we just started on graphics. I have done two assignments using actionListener. In both assignments my constructors have this code:

```
JButton.setActionListener(this) ;
```

So my question here is what would happen if I used a different class, instead of the "this" keyword?

ex

```
JButton.setActionListener(someClass) ;
```

Comment: That would depend on a lot of things. First both classes would need to implement `ActionListener`. Using a different class would mean that you would lose reference to the class in which the button is defined (although you can still get a reference to it via the `ActionEvent#getSource` method, it means you won't be able to access any of the instance fields/methods of the defining class)

Comment: It would also highly recommend having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Basically you're doing it right.  `this` gets used a lot in short examples because you can add a method to an existing class and the code takes less space.  Normally you don't want to reuse classes like that, you want to separate concerns, so you should have a different class be your action listener.

Comment: *"So my question here is what would happen if I used a different class, instead of the "this" keyword?"* - The world would come to a crashing and horrible end ... no seriously, the question is vague at best. You might get a compiler error if you've not implemented `ActionListener`, if you have, then your "other" class will not be able to reference the calling class or any of its instance fields or methods, without first passing a reference of itself to the other, which is not a "bad" thing per say, but can lead to some difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an instance of ActionListener ( even anonymous classes are allowed ). 
So you can do something like:

```
new JButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //YOUR CODE
        }
    });
```

Or you can implement an other class (lets call it Foo) and add it with

```
new JButton().addActionListener(new Foo());
```

And in case you like functional programming you can also use a lambda expression ;)

Comment: And obviously Foo.class needs to implement ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

It means that that class `someClass` must `implements` `ActionListener`together with its implemented methods like `actionperformed()` method.

Like:

```
public class SomeClass implements ActionListener {


        public SomeClass() {

                //Could do things here
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //DDo things when button is clicked.
                System.out.println("The button has been clicked");
        }

}
```

Comment: `Button` is an AWT based class, best to avoid using it

Comment: Exactly @MadProgrammer , sorry about that.